# Can someone kick the diamond cache on Kevin Montrose's profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderators

It appears that [valued associate #00004](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/11/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/) is no longer with the SE team. I don't know exactly when he left, but according to the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) it was somewhere between [May 7<sup>th</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507051012/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) and [July 14<sup>th</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20210714192547/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose).
However, he still has his diamond in the sidebar of [his profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose):

[image]

Can someone kick the cache? It has been like this since at least 02:30 today, as it was spotted by [Ekadh Singh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/560258/ekadh-singh-reinstate-monica) [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9008748#9008748).

Comment: I [brought this up](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58725710#58725710) with Catija on Jul 27th, apparently they're "looking into it"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All done. The list of accounts *is* cached, but it fundamentally is powered by a database table that aggregates some basic metadata about an account's profiles from across the network, and the user type for Kevin's MSE profile had the wrong value in there.

Thanks for the report!